# What do "in-country mobilities" and "policy stringency" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today I saw a paragraph relating to the Covid-19 pandemic

> The effects of government public health policies varied wildly
> regarding their effectiveness in controlling the transmission of the
> Covid-19 virus. Even with the same level of **policy stringency**, the
> levels of **in-country mobilities** widely varied, causing the
> inconsistent policy effectiveness across countries

I am wondering what do " **in-country mobilities** " and " **policy stringency** "  mean

Comment: Have you looked up *stringency* in a dictionary? It's cognate with *strictness*.  And *mobilty*? Merriam-Webster has a definition for *in-country*.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thanks a heap, but I mean, I do not fully understand, I need some examples to understand what they calll "policy stringency", and from your source, I understand the abstarct meaning of "in-country" and "mobilities", but when merge these two words together, the meaning becomes very ambiguous to me. Could you please help me to sort it out? Warm regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this quote "policy stringency" means the degree of strictness of the policy, or perhaps how strictly it is enforced.

I take "in-country mobilities" to mean the amount of moving around that people do within the country. I think this use of "mobilities" is wrong or at best awkward. It should be at least the singular "mobility", but rephrasing would be better.

This sounds to me like bureaucratese.

I would rephrase

> Even with the same level of policy stringency, the levels of in-country mobilities widely varied, causing the inconsistent policy effectiveness across countries

as something like:

> Even when policies are enforced with equal strictness, the amout of travel that people did within the country varied widely from one country to another. That is why specific policies were much more effective in some countries than in others.

Same meaning, but much clearer, in my view.